# Why were Jakku and Hosnian Prime invented instead of setting the action on Tatooine and Coruscant?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

For Star Wars episode 7, why did they invent the planet Jakku (which looks identical to Tatooine) and Hosnian Prime (capital planet looking identical to Coruscant) instead of a setting on Tatooine and Coruscant? I'm sure many watchers (me included) thought these planets actually *are* Tatooine and Coruscant until learning the filmmakers invented new planets. What was the point of that? Just curious.

Comment: In the case of Coruscant, probably they did not want Coruscant to be destroyed.

Comment: @suchiuomizu They could have done it vice versa: Hosnian Prime as a new planet after a destruction of Coruscant. Not that I'd take the last 3 episodes as canon, anyway. :-)

Comment: It evolved from a junk planet into a desert planet with a lot of junk; https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1659499/star-wars-almost-went-with-a-much-different-look-for-jakku

Comment: @Valorum What you mean is that it was originally concepted as a junk planet.

Comment: @John - Indeedy. And that article would probably make the nice basis for a partial answer.

Comment: @Valorum Still I wonder why they didn't make it a junk planet then, it would have been quite a different planet. The article suggests that it would've been easier for Rey/Kira to survive with so much junk if it was that way.

Comment: What would be the point of using the same planets again? It's supposed to be a whole galaxy.

Comment: @OrangeDog The planets' appearances are identical to the other two. If they wanted the same landscape, the question is what's the point of creating new planets.

Comment: Yeah, the new trilogy had a very bizarre mix trying to be new while paying constant homage to the old movies. "Sometimes you must kill the past! Oh look, it's the Not Rebels and the Not Empire and their Not Death Star, the Millennium Falcon, Han Solo, Yoda, Lando. What was I saying? Oh right. Let the past die!"

Comment: Wouldn't it be remarkable that Tattooine - an Outer Rim backwater planet not even under the control of the Republic and barely held under the Empire - would be the source for yet another Jedi? People would start to think there's something in the vaporated moisture (or maybe it's the blue milk).

Comment: Identical? Psch. Jakku has totally different sand. It’s fine, and soft, and pleasing, and always stays in the desert.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, but at least for the Jakku part of the question I think it's because of the Imperial wreckage there; it likely would have seemed weird to insert an entire battle on an established planet like Tatooine. Besides that, they probably just wanted to switch up the scenery a little bit.

Comment: @user103390 What dya mean by 'established planet'? Tatooine in the outer rim is barely controlled by the Republic/Empire, lacking law and order mostly or having its own laws (such as slavery); it would surely be a place where one could dispose of any former war machines, in one of its deserts.

Comment: @John that's true that it could be a useful place to dispose wreckage, but it does seem a little bit strange that they would dispose of them at all. By 'established planet' I mean like established in the Star Wars universe that we, the watchers, know of. Again, this is a lot of guesswork--this could all be completely unrelated to the real reason they invented new planets. :)

Answer (score 1):

At one point in Bad Robot's (JJ Abrams's production company's) writing process for *The Force Awakens*, it **was** going to be Coruscant that got blown up by Starkiller Base, but the idea was nixed by Lucasfilm. This was confirmed in January 2022 by Lucasfilm's Pablo Hidalgo in a [now-deleted tweet](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1481688997571088385) ([archived](https://archive.ph/jDWgX)):

[image: Screenshot of tweets (transcribed below)]

> @StarWarsLiker: At the risk of being impertinent, this reminds me… back in the day I asked this, and if memory serves you said ask again after episode 9. However, I’d totally understand if you were to demur such a question these days.
>
> > @StarWarsLiker: @pabl0hidalgo Do you happen to know whose idea it was to make Hosnian Prime the capital in 7? Did J.J. or Larry really say ‘we want to blow up the capital of the republic but don’t want it to be Coruscant’ or did someone else suggest changing it to preserve Coruscant?
>
> @pabl0hidalgo: Basically BR wanted it blown up; LFL didn’t. Hosnian Prime was the unsatisfying middle ground. It happens.
>
> @pabl0hidalgo: (I should say ‘some folks at’ because it’s not like companies have points of view)

Later, he [followed up](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1483137487346098176) to clarify that this was because Coruscant "had the potential to be featured in something else in development", though without specifying whether this was a particular later work (eg Colin Trevorrow's Episode IX) or just later Star Wars works in general.

> [@pabl0hidalgo:](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1483137487346098176) It’s not all that deep. The concept art resembles Coruscant because for a time it was; but that planet had the potential to be featured in something else in development so it was changed to a different location. Not really all that newsworthy. ‍♂️

In the same thread, he mentions that the idea for Jakku was driven by the planet being a junkyard for ships from the Original Trilogy, not by it being a desert planet, and that (as far as he knows) it was never planned to be Tatooine:

> [@Sassy_Ewok:](https://twitter.com/Sassy_Ewok/status/1483260636507385862) Was there something similar with Jakku/Tatooine?
>
> [@pabl0hidalgo:](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1483261020122411008) Not that I know of. As the concept art shows, Jakku wasn't necessarily a desert planet. Just a planet with a lot of old junk.

This is supported by *The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, which has a whole section about early story concepts for the then-anonymous "Junk Planet":

> The seeds of a junk planet concept were born out of the very first Visualist meeting on January 9[, 2013], in which a crashed Imperial space station was discussed. Not long after, they proposed the idea of a wrecked Imperial Star Destroyer. Reference imagery of the shipbreaking yards of the modern-day Indian subcontinent were combined with these ideas, and the planet of Jakku began to take shape.
>
> (page 25)

[image: Concept art showing AT-ATs being deconstructed in a wet environment]

Comment: In fairness to LucasFilm, their plan was to set a lot of Rebels and their new series on Coruscant and having it get blown up would make all of those stories pointless if you know that everyone you see will be dead in a few years